# Can the Lutron Accessory Switch be used alone

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I purchased the Lutron dimmer & accessory switch combo.

I want to use the accessory switch alone for a light. Is that possible? Or does it need to connect to the dimmer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it can not be used as a single switch. It has to be used in conjunction with another switch/dimmer.

Answer (score 3):

The Lutron remotes can't do anything useful by themselves. They must be paired with a Lutron switch or dimmer that is wired to the load.

Answer (score -2):

For the pico remotes, as others have said, you need to use them with an existing switch.

Lutron sells a "pedestal" which is nice for leaving the pico remote out on e.g. an end table.

There's also a mounting kit for putting the remote on the wall. So if the room has multiple entrances, you can have something resembling a three-way switch setup without any wiring.

Or if you get one of the other caseta appliances, like a lamp dimmer, or an outdoor plug, then you can use the pico with that. For instance, you could get a lamp dimmer, and put a floor lamp on it. Then put a 2-gang plate over your in-wall dimmer, with the pico next to it. Now you have switches for your built-in light and your floor lamp side-by-side.

But the short version is that the remote can be paired with any caseta appliance and there are a couple of mounting options, so they are useful. I have one stuck to the headboard of my bed :)

Comment: I suspect the remote the OP is referring to is one of the *wired* remote switches used with Maestro dimmers for multi-way control, *not* the Pico remotes used as part of the Lutron Caseta system.